# Good resources on applying Earned Value Management

Tags: planning, process, evm

Two part question -

**First** - I have a basic understanding of Earned Value Management (EVM), but the example I've found so far on applying seem vague. So any suggestions on understanding EVM more? I'm mainly trying to find examples on how best to calculate the Projected Value and the Earned Value (e.g. real world example showing how milestones are mapped, etc.)

**Second** - Any suggestions on how something like Scrum could be mapped to EVM? Thinking iterations and story points could be mapped back, but again need help visualizing it.

Comment: Can you link to the vague example so we'll have some context for answering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best source of practical knowledge on EVM is [Glen Alleman's blog](http://herdingcats.typepad.com).

A couple of articles which you may find useful to understand EVM better:

- [Minimum Elements of EVM](http://herdingcats.typepad.com/my_weblog/2009/08/minimum-elements-of-an-earned-value-system.html)
- [Earned Value is not the same as Business Value](http://herdingcats.typepad.com/my_weblog/2011/05/alert-earned-value-is-not-the-same-as-business-value.html)

And a couple more on using EVM in agile context:

- [What does it mean when someone says Agile EVM](http://herdingcats.typepad.com/my_weblog/2010/11/what-does-it-mean-when-someone-says-agile-evm.html)
- [Agile and EVM Part 1](http://herdingcats.typepad.com/my_weblog/2011/05/agile-and-evm.html)
- [Agile and EVM Part 2](http://herdingcats.typepad.com/my_weblog/2011/06/agile-and-evm-part-two.html)

You will find more in the archives of the site.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting article regarding Earned Value and Agile is

[Earning Value the Agile Way: Using Story Points to generate EV Metrics](http://www.mgmt-technologies.com/Earning%20Value%20the%20Agile%20Way.pdf)

It provides a good comparison of EVM and Agile, the difference between CPI and Velocity etc.

Otherwise I second Glen Alleman's blog.